# jQuery animation in sequence

Tags: jquery

I have a few div elements that i want to dynamically apply an effect to in sequence.
These divs are loaded from an array so I cant manually construct the animation like this

```
$(segment).animate({
    opacity: 0
}, 100, function(){
    $(segment).animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 100);
});
```

Any idea how to solve this problem?
Somebody else suggested i use the jQuery queue but that seems to just create a queue for each element.

Comment: I think that jquery queue is just meant for this kind of situations...

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want apply the animate on each DIV one by one : after the end of animation one the first DIV, the second start the animation an so on. That's right ?

Comment: I think he's just trying to reproduce the pulsate effect of jQuery UI...

Comment: na, that was just a quick example i came up with... I am currently loading a number of random divs into an array and want to go through each of them applying an effect. If i use a foreach loop then all of the effects happen simultaneously... i want to perform an effect of the array one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used jquery queue that everyone mentioned so just used an array and a timer. Heres the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/5MyQU/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var __THEDIVS = [];

    $('div').each(function() {
        __THEDIVS.push($(this));
    })

    function animate() {
        $elem = __THEDIVS.pop();
        $elem.animate({
            'height': '100px'
        }, 200);
        if (__THEDIVS.length) {
            setTimeout(animate, 500);
        }
    }
    animate();
})
```

Some HTML

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Cool... that's exactly what i want.